# How to find an iFrame element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm trying to find iFrame Web Element but i'm getting "No Such Element Excecption".

This is the way that i'm trying to locate the iFrame:

```
@FindBy(id="iframe_uz04pghfaa")
public WebElement ifrmContactIframe;

public void SwitchToIframe() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException 
{       
    try 
    {
        ifrmContactIframe.isDisplayed();    //if the element is displayed it means that he exist
        driver.switchTo().frame(ifrmContactIframe);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        fail("Element does not exist"); 
    }
}
```

HTML Snapshot:
[image: This is picture of the site code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the ID changes on each refresh? `.isDisplayed()` checks more than just if the element exists... it checks to see if it's visible. You shouldn't need that check because if it doesn't exist, the next line will fail anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your frame is being generated randomly,In Your method, Try Following:

```
    try 
        {
            List<WebElement> totalFrames = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*[id^='iframe_'"));
            System.out.println("Total FRMAES =" + totalFrames .size()); 
            ifrmContactIframe = totalFrames.get(0);

            ifrmContactIframe.isDisplayed();    //if the element is displayed it means that he exist
            driver.switchTo().frame(ifrmContactIframe);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            fail("Element does not exist"); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate and switch to the *iFrame* you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[id^='iframe_'][name^='iframe_'][src^='/crm/contact/details/']")));
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id,'iframe_') and starts-with(@name,'iframe_')][starts-with(@src, '/crm/contact/details/')]")));
    ```

**PS**: Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: @Liorp _FrameId_ and _FrameName_ are dynamically generated. _implicitlyWait_ won't be enough. You need _WebDriverWait_.

Comment: I tried the Wait option but it still doesn't recognize the iFrame: 
' new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("iframe_uz04pghfaa")));'

Comment: @Liorp Where did you find **By.id("iframe_uz04pghfaa")** within this answer?

Comment: I thought that i saw it in one of the answers but never mind, i changed it to the 'By.name' but it still doesn't find the iFrame:


'new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("iframe_uz04pghfaa"))); '

By the way what's the difference between searching by name or by id?

Comment: @Liorp Where did you even find **By.name("iframe_uz04pghfaa")** within this answer?

Comment: In one of your previous comments about "Ways to deal with #document under iframe"